# Delete parameter & returning back unsuccsessful Ids

Tags: c#

Is this possible?

I get comma separated IDs as a integer/string arrays as a param (ie. 100,101,102,103,104,105).

I need to pass into in a delete query.

ie. `delete from tablename where ID in (100,101,102,103,104,105) and status='Completed';`

If 100,102,105 gets deleted & if 101 & 103 don't get deleted (for some error), then i need to return back 101 & 103 not deleted with error message(if status is not completed).

Pls. throw some lights on this.

Comment: hmmm, unclear, please clarify.

Comment: Why would any of those records not get deleted, other than they don't exist?

Comment: Why not just process the IDs individually, and build a `List` of some sort to return.  Could be a custom class, dictionary, or a list of tuples.

Comment: @gorilla - the delete could fail due to referential integrity constraints.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the query.

Comment: @Robaticus - Thanks for the point, yes i have seen many of those referential integrity fails.

Comment: Is that really C#? Please consider retagging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a transaction and split into two operations. First you delete everything in the list, then you query for everything in the list and you will get a list of those that weren't deleted. After that just complete the transaction.

**EDIT:** Not even sure you need a transaction, it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What it comes down to is that you're going to need to process each ID individually and determine whether or not the delete succeeds.  As I said in my comment, you have a variety of choices on what you return back to the calling process.  It could be a `List<CustomClass>` a `Dictionary<int, string>`, or even a list of tuples.

I personally tend to use `List<CustomClass>`, because when I return two things (e.g. ID and error), I always wind up wanting to return more later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SQL stored procedure to accomplish this.  Call the sproc using the list of ids, and have the sproc return a table of ids and the reason it did not succeed.

Comment: Thanks but stored procedure is not used due to some reasons.